# How to handle wait message poup when we try to download files using protractor

Tags: protractor

I am able to download files which are of less size, but when I am trying to download big files I am getting pop div with message please wait. This is happening only for large files. Could you please tell me how to handle this. My configurations are as below.

```
prefs: {
  download: {
     'prompt_for_download': false,
     'directory_upgrade': true,
     'default_directory': 'E:/Download_Pro/test'
   }
}
```

Comment: `prompt_for_download` should work.  Also why are you saving to drive E?  C is typically your hard drive

Comment: Saving to drive is not a problem as by default it is downloading to default downloads folder. Just I would like to download into separate folder. Problem is with pop message for large files.